# How to target JVM 9 on Kotlin with Gradle?

Tags: gradle, kotlin

Targeting JVM 1.8 on Kotlin with Gradle is as easy as

```
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

But that doesn't work for Java 9 if I simply change the `jvmTarget` to `9` or `1.9`. How can I do it?

Comment: which version of Gradle did you use?

Comment: I used Gradle v4.2.1

Comment: I don't think there is a special "1.9" mode at all. Leave `jvmTarget = "1.8"` and and it should work as-is.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Kotlin currently only targets Java 6 and 8

See the FAQs here https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/faq.html#does-kotlin-only-target-java-6

Which at the moment says

> Does Kotlin only target Java 6?
>   No. Kotlin lets you choose between generating Java 6 and Java 8 compatible bytecode. More optimal byte code may be generated for higher versions of the platform.

---

edit:

So... because it's the compatibility of the bytecode that kotlin is generating it doesn't mean that fixes the Java version you need to use.

Here's a gradle file that let's you use Java 11 alongside kotlin generating Java 8 compatible bytecode

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.2.71'
}

group 'com.dambra.paul.string-calculator'
version '0.0.0'

sourceCompatibility = 11.0

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation(
            'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.1.0'
    )
    testRuntimeOnly(
            'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.1.0'
    )
    testCompile("org.assertj:assertj-core:3.11.1")
    testCompile 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.1.0'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
}
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

You can't "target jvm 9" with Kotlin. But you can write Kotlin alongside Java (9|10|11|etc)

Comment: At current date this answer seems correct; it would be nice an explanation for the down vote for others to understand too what’s wrong about it.

Comment: Kotlin now allow targeting Java versions from 6 to 12 https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#attributes-specific-for-jvm

Answer (score 7):

See the [Kotlin "Using Gradle" reference "Attributes specific for the JVM"](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#attributes-specific-for-jvm) for possible values of the attribute `jvmTarget`:

> Name: `jvmTarget`
>
> Description: Target version of the generated JVM bytecode (1.6, 1.8, 9, 10, 11 or 12), default is 1.6
>
> Possible values: "1.6", "1.8", "9", "10", "11", "12"
>
> Default value: "1.6"
>
> *Copied 2019/10/01*

Answer (score 0):

I am using vsc "visual studio code". If you have a build.gradle file , you will see "// Apply a specific Java toolchain to ease working on different environments.
"java {
toolchain {
languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(8)`/enter code here`/
}
}"

enter it here : JavaLanguageVersion.of()